# Spying on property changes with Sinon

Tags: javascript, sinon, stubbing

I am stubbing properties with sinon. I have trouble understanding how the related spying works. Most of the sinon spy methods seem to be related to function calls and not to access of object properties. As a workaround I created a variable for tracking the property access and set it manually when the related getter function is called. See the code example below. This seems to work just fine but I feel like I am probably duplicating some functionality that already exists in sinon. What would be a more idiomatic way of achieving the same result?

```js
      const sinon = require('sinon');
      const lib = require('./lib');
      const app = require('./app');

      const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

      let fooAccessed = false;

      sandbox.stub(lib, 'foo').get(() => {
        fooAccessed = true;
        return 123
      });

      app();

      expect(fooAccessed).toEqual(true);
```

Comment: Why not a Proxy object?

Comment: I realised the problem I'm trying to solve is not related to environment variables specifically but object properties more generally. I removed the environment variables from the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably not the answer you want, because i do not use "sinon", but i will answer anyway. Perhaps this helps you in any way.

You can use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object to intercept accessing a object.

```js
const obj = {
    foo: "bar",
    baz: true
};

let accessed = false;

const proxied = new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, prop) {
        if (prop === "foo") {
            accessed = true;
        }
        return target[prop];
    }
});

console.log(proxied, accessed);
console.log(proxied.foo);
console.log(proxied, accessed);
```

Result:

```
{ foo: 'bar', baz: true } false
bar
{ foo: 'bar', baz: true } true
```

Comment: The main reason for using sinon in this case is that app imports the library directly. Sinon injects code into the library at runtime so tests are able to control and monitor the behaviour without adding permanent test controls to the app or the library.